# SDK2: Issues with Rally Grids

Tags: javascript, rally

SDK2 Rally grids are seriously great and flexible, but there are a few significant issues I have run into:

1. % done columns like LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal for Portfolio Items show orange arrows when there is an issue (like not all stories have plan estimate), but there in no popup (which you get when viewing them in Plan -> Portfolio items)
2. No drag and drop ranking
3. No coherent display of the rank field (it shows the raw real number)

Are these on the near term roadmap?  Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The PercentDone tooltips should work.  Are you getting any script errors in the console when hovering over the PercentDone bar in your grid?

2) You should be able to simply set enableRanking to true in the config when creating the grid: http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid-cfg-enableRanking

(It shouldn't be necessary to include the Rank field in the grid to enable this functionality)

3) Currently there is no built-in way to show the friendly rank like the Backlog page does.  You would have to implement a custom renderer for the Rank column:

```
columnCfgs: [
    'FormattedID',
    'Name',
    {
        text: 'Rank',
        dataIndex: 'Rank',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            //Use this info to render the friendly rank
            return rowIndex + 1;
        }
    }
]
```

Note the above really only works when the grid is sorted by Rank- it was more an example of how to specify a custom renderer.

Comment: Thanks on the Drag and drop-- works great!  But still having trouble with PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate for PI's-- still not getting a popup with the orange triangle, and I don't see any errors in the console (using Chrome)